# How to construct a smooth curve whose range is dense in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

How to construct a smooth curve $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$   whose range is dense in $\mathbb R^2$?

[Space-filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) are well-known, but they *cannot* be smooth.   The image of a smooth function  $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ is a countable union of curves of finite length, so it has zero area.

Here, a smooth function is a function which has derivatives of all orders. Roughly, this curve has no sharp corners.

Comment: My first thought is to use the topologist's sine curve in some way.

Comment: Is this link what you are looking for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_curve

Comment: Enumerate the circles with rational center and radius. Parametrize each by the interval $[2k,2k+1]$. Use the intervals $[2k+1,2k+2]$ to smoothly connect.

Comment: Since "smooth" is used in a variety of different ways, you should explicitly indicate which meaning of "smooth" you are interested in.

Comment: @Nimda I don't think that's smooth.

Comment: @CareBear Nice!  It would be simpler to enumerate the points $q_k \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ and let $f(k) = q_k$ and "connect the dots" with smooth curves.

Comment: @augurar indeed, my mistake, I took smooth for continuous.

Comment: @CareBear You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @augurar Done. I modified the example to make the details of $C^\infty$ smoothness easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This example works for all $\mathbb R^n$, $n\ge 2$.

Pick a countable dense subset of $\mathbb R^n$, call it $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$. For each $n\in\mathbb Z$, choose an oriented line segment with midpoint at $x_n$;  call it $I_n$. Map $[4n-1,4n+1]$ onto $I_n$ by an affine map $f$, so that $f(4n)=x_n$. Also map $[4n+1,4n+3]$ onto the line segment connecting the end of $I_n$ to the beginning of $I_{n+1}$. We now have a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$.

Then [mollify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier)  $f$ to $g=f*\phi$, where $\phi$ is a symmetric bump supported on $[-1,1]$. Observe that 
$$
g(4n) = \int_{-1}^1 f(4n-t)\phi(t)\,dt = f(4n) = x_n
$$
because integration against the even function $\phi$ kills the linear term in $f(4n-t)$.

Thus, $g$ is $C^\infty$ smooth and its image contains $D$.

Comment: I assume $D$ in the last sentence refers to the countable dense subset?

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I originally has $D=\{x_n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ but somehow over-edited. Guess it's not worth bumping, though