# Finding a smooth curve $\alpha: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R^n$ such that $\overline{\alpha(\Bbb R)} = \Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, curves

I was reviewing my notes from a Differential Geometry course I took last year, and I started thinking of the following problem$\color{blue}{^1}$.

> Let $n \ge 2$. Does there exist a smooth curve $\alpha: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R^n$ satisfying $\overline{\alpha(\Bbb R)} = \Bbb R^n$, i.e., the **trajectory** of the curve is **dense** in $\Bbb R^n$?

It is not immediately clear that such a curve *exists* in the first place, but an explicit *construction* shall take that problem off our hands.

---

**Some Thoughts:** Since $\Bbb R^n$ is separable, let us choose a countable dense subset $S:= \{x_k\}_{k\in \Bbb Z}$ of $\Bbb R^n$. For every $k\in \Bbb Z$, define $\alpha$ on the closed interval $[k,k+1]$ as the segment joining $x_k$ to $x_{k+1}$. Then, the trajectory of $\alpha$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$, but the curve obtained is not necessarily *smooth.* Perhaps there is some way to modify the $\alpha$ so obtained, to "smoothen" it around the corners?

Is the problem easier to solve when $n = 2$? Maybe we can take $n = 2$ as our guiding light to generalize to higher dimensions.

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks a lot.

---

P.S.

- By a "curve", I really mean a *regular* curve, i.e., $\alpha'(t) \ne 0$ for all $t\in \Bbb R$, but please feel free to drop this assumption if that is really needed. Furthermore, it would be good if we can prevent the curve from intersecting itself.
- Smooth means $\mathcal C^\infty$.

$\color{blue}{1.}$ The source of this problem is my *imagination*, so I cannot comment on the difficulty and/or solvability of the same. It doesn't seem out of the scope of a first course in differential geometry, though.

Comment: Does smooth mean $C^1$ or better? BTW, by invariance of domain, any one-to-one *continuous* map maps homeomorphically to its image?

Comment: @TedShifrin Smooth means $\mathcal C^\infty$. What's "invariance of domain"? I don't see why the inverse must be continuous.

Comment: It’s a rather deep result from algebraic topology. For $C^1$ maps, it’s a consequence of the inverse function theorem. Anyhow, worth googling. Your question is somewhat deep, as there is a dense smooth curve on a torus and $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb R$ is dense in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Your argument is fine. Further, there are continuous maps from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]x[0,1]$ so called Peano's curve. So, arguing in a  similar way, there are continuous maps from $R$ onto $R^2$ (i.e. no clouser is needed) and this is true for any $n$.

Comment: @Salcio This does not address the smooth case. The space-filling curve constructions are very non-differentiable.

Comment: A smoothening of a piecewise linear curve should work. If you make sure that your curve stays at each $x_k$ for some time $t > 0$ and use convolution with radius $<t$, the smooth curve will also pass through $x_k$.

Comment: With some work, it should also be possible to have nonzero velocity everywhere. For this, one could start with a p.l.c. (piecewise linear curve) which is linear _around_ each $x_k$ for time $t>0$. Taking care of the order of $x_k$'s, one can then make sure that the p.l.c. doesn't make sharp turns, which implies that the smoothening still has nonzero velocity.

Comment: One way to do the smoothing part of the construction is explained [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942509/how-to-construct-a-smooth-curve-whose-range-is-dense-in-mathbb-r2). Note that their post does not require the curve to be regular.

Comment: Cubic splines can be pieced together so that the points of intersection are smooth. You may be able to stitch them together to approximate non-differentiable space filling curves.